# How to do where like on joined table columns in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I got two tables to join

```
Table name: keywords

{ 
    id: int,
    location_id: int,
    keys: string
}

Table name: comments

{ 
    id: int,
    location_id: int,
    comment: string
}
```

I need to join and count the number of comments that have the keywords in the comments.

Here's my initial code:

```
DB::table('keywords')
    ->select('keywords.key', DB::raw('COUNT(comments.id) as count'))
    ->join('comments', 'comments.location_id', '=', 'keywords.location_id')
    ->where(????);
```

How do I get roughly this result?

```
{
    key: 'sample',
    count: 3
},
{
    key: 'hi',
    count: 2
}
```

Comment: add ```->groupBy('keywords.keys')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call the joined columns just like you call it inside select

```
$key_word = 'hi'; // this is just an example
// you can use $key = request()->input('search_key') 

DB::table('keywords')
    ->select('keywords.key', DB::raw('COUNT(comments.id) as count'))
    ->join('comments', 'comments.location_id', '=', 'keywords.location_id')
    ->where('comments.comment', 'like', "%{$key_word}%")
    ->groupBy('keywords.key')
    ->get();
```

And if you have more than one key words

```
->where('comments.comment', 'like', "%{$key_word_1}%")
->orWhere('comments.comment', 'like', "%{$key_word_2}%")
->orWhere('comments.comment', 'like', "%{$key_word_3}%")
...
```

**UPDATE**:

comment from **TheGPWorx**
*"what I meant is that the key should be the key value in the keywords.key column in the other table"*

**Solution** to use column keywords.key as search parameter

```
$query->where('comments.comment', 'like', DB::raw("CONCAT('%', keywords.key, '%')"
```

Comment: I need to have the $key to be dynamic.

Comment: how do  you do comments.comments like '%keywords.key%'?

Comment: yes the key is dynamic, you can enter anything you like, even from request input , `$key = request()->input('search_key')`

Comment: what I meant is that the key should be the key value in the keywords.key column in the other table

Comment: to use from column keywords.key , try `->where('comments.comment', 'like', DB::raw("CONCAT('%', keywords.key, '%')"`

Comment: I'm glad can help you. I have updated my answer. Have a nice day.